# How to replace a particular text between 2 characters in a string

Tags: php, regex

I have a doubt in regular expression. I want to replace a particular text which is present in 2 characters in a string.

Example:

```
$my_string = "newtext!234@@random_text@@weludud";
$new_text  = 'replaced_text";
```

In myabove string I want to replace the text between my characters @@. So in the above string I want to replace random_text with replaced_text.

So my output will be `newtext!234@@replaced_text@@weludud`

Comment: Please show your regular expression

Comment: Does the `@@...@@` combination only occurs once in the string?

Comment: Yes Michel it only occurs once

Answer (score 2):

If `@@ text @@` appears only once in the string, you can use `explode`.

```
$my_string = "newtext!234@@random_text@@weludud"; 
$new_text = 'replaced_text';
$var = explode('@@',$my_string); //create an array with 3 parts, the middle one being the text to be replaced

$var[1]=$new_text;

$my_string=implode('@@',$var);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=@@)(?:(?!@@).)*(?=@@)
```

Try this.Replace by `replace_text`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/sU3fA2/40

Answer (score 0):

```
$my_string = "newtext!234@@random_text@@weludud";
$replace = 'replaced_text'; 
$replaced_text = preg_replace('#(@)(.*)(@)#si', "$1$replace$3", $my_string);
echo $replaced_text;
```

[**Working demo**](http://3v4l.org/JiUFf)